# Spark, CLI and building using SBT

Tags: sbt, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to build a simple database based on Apache Spark SQL. For this purpose, I have created a Apache Spark SQL project and have written some Scala classes written that do some calculations. I would like to run Spark with a CLI (and/or JDBC) interface and be able to access the functions I wrote.

I have spark building and running using SBT (in IntelliJ). If I understood correctly, for the CLI thrive is necessary. Therefore, I have added to my SBT build file

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Pyarn", "-Phadoop-2.3", "-Phive", "-Phive-thriftserver")
```

However, I get a bad option error. How can I compile and assemble the project and how can I then proceed to run the CLI?

Answer (score 0):

First, you might find it useful to fork the JVM when you run. Add this setting if so:

`fork in run := true`

Either way, to pass options to the JVM when you run, use this for example:

`javaOptions in run ++= Seq("-Xmx8G", ...)`

Note that the `scalacOptions` only affects compilation.

What are the `-P...` options intended to do? I'm not familiar with them. Note that if they are supposed to be passed to a shell script, this won't happen, as you're invoking the JVM directly.

Comment: Apparently, the `-P` options denotes Maven profiles; I found this in the [Documentation]{https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-with-sbt}, however, the example shown there does not work for me.